# Insert multiple data into database in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have problem with my code when i'm trying to save multiple data into database at the same time, this is my code to save into database:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
   $model->route = $value[0][1];
   $model->begin_point = $value[0][2];
   $model->begin_point = $value[0][3];
   $model->save();
}
return $this->redirect('index');
```

every i'm trying to save, i'm only get the last data array can save into database. could someone help me? or if someone could provide a tutorial, that would be a real help.

Comment: you can use batchInsert() to insert multiple records at a time. For more details: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert%28%29-detail

Comment: @chinmay thank you, is so usefull

Answer (score 12):

1. Create an array by looping your multiple values.

   ```
   $data- has multiple values
   $bulkInsertArray = array();
   foreach($data as $value){
      $bulkInsertArray[]=[
          'columnName1'=>$value[0][1],
          'columnName2'=>$value[0][2],
          'columnName3'=>$value[0][3]
      ];
   }
   ```
2. Check $bulkInsertArray in not empty

   ```
   if(count($bulkInsertArray)>0){
       $columnNameArray=['columnName1','columnName2','columnName3'];
       // below line insert all your record and return number of rows inserted
       $insertCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                      ->batchInsert(
                            $tableName, $columnNameArray, $bulkInsertArray
                        )
                      ->execute();
   }
   ```

Hope these code may be helpful.

Comment: This works fine.
You can get tableName using YourModelName::getTableSchema()->name

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a New object of the model each time. Or Else youre Just overwriting.

Comment: Not when you use Yii's db command. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html - Using an object in a loop would be very inefficient and a terrible solution, especially for potentially large amounts of data. Your really going to load an object 1,000 times in a loop to import 1,000 items? Here is a side-by-side breakdown showing the differences and uses: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/insert-query/ - To the op, look at the batch insert as @Kailas answered. For really large imports, split the data into batches of say 500/loop.

Comment: Question: One of the API's I am using (which is awful) returns all records (about 3,000 in total) - i want to do a batch upload but only of new records and altered records, how would i do that without a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use Yii command builder to achieve this.

```html
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();

$command->insert('table_name',array('column_1'=>$value_1),
'column_2'=>$value_2));
```

and so on.

2. Write this code in loop and it will insert all records one after another.

Comment: isn't it going to shortened our store life?
cz if i have 250000 data then i need to write 250000 times to my storage, rather than just write one time with bigger size to write?
or is it will gave the same result to our storage??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yes It Is Batch Insert to insert multiple rows. It is faster than any of the ways stated here :

```
$connection->createCommand()->batchInsert('table_name', ['table_column_1', 'table_column_2'], [
    ['column_1_data_a', 'column_2_data_a'],
    ['column_1_data_b', 'column_2_data_b'],
    ['column_1_data_c', 'column_2_data_c'],
])->execute();
```

Check the link for [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail).

Answer (score 0):

I think batch insert is the best solution for this problem.

but there is one problem with your pic of code that is **this code will create only one data row(first row) in data table and update to that same model**

solution for your code is

```
 foreach ($data as $value) {
    $model = new Model(); // creating new instance of model 
    $model->route = $value[0][1];
    $model->begin_point = $value[0][2];
    $model->begin_point = $value[0][3];
    $model->save();
  }
  return $this->redirect('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
   $model = new ModelNeme(); //optional
   $model->route = $_POST['name'][$key];
   $model->save();
}
return $this->redirect('index');
```