# Bulk insert or update yii2

Tags: cakephp, yii, yii2, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

**What I did**

I am inserting bulk data in table as follows:

```
if(count($bulkInsertArray)>0){
    $columnNameArray=['columnName1','columnName2','columnName3'];
    // below line insert all your record and return number of rows inserted
    $insertCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                   ->batchInsert(
                         $tableName, $columnNameArray, $bulkInsertArray
                     )
                   ->execute();
}
```

REF: [Insert multiple data into database in Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272150/insert-multiple-data-into-database-in-yii-2)

and here insert working fine.

**What I want:**

Now My question is can we do something like **if here columnName1 is private key and if we are passing null value for that column then perform insert operation otherwise perform update operation**.

Same concept working in CAKEPHP.

I am using YII2.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 doesn't provide "upsert" logic. 
You need split it in two operations: 
1) insert without duplicates (queries bellow) 
2) update

```
--don't insert user if login already exists
insert into users(login, name)
select *
from 
(
    select
    'l_john' as login,
    'John' as name
    union 
    select
    'l_mike' as login,
    'Mike' as name
) q
left join users u
on u.login = q.login
where u.id is null
```

or

```
create temp table tmp_users(login, name);

insert into tmp_users(login, name) values
('l_john', 'John'),
('l_mike', 'Mike');

insert into users(login, name)
select tu.login, tu.name
from tmp_users ti
left join users u
on u.login = tu.login
```

second query set is more fastest

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so lot but at the end completed it with loop like:

```
            foreach ($table_info_arr as $table_info)
            {
                $table_info_sql = array();

                $model = tableInfo::find()->where(["columnName1_id" => $table_info['columnName1_id']])->one();
                if (empty($model))
                {
                    $model = new tableInfo();
                }
                $matches_info_sql['tableInfo'] = $table_info;

                $model->load($table_info_sql);
                $model->save(false);
            }
```

Let me know if is there any better solution